# How Do I Stop Intellij Automatically Shortening Code Blocks?

Tags: macos, osx-mountain-lion, intellij-idea

[image: intellij shortened code]

How do I stop the arrow thing from showing up. I know that, if I click on it, it will expand but I would prefer that it be expanded by default. I'm using OSX Mountain Lion.

Comment: This sounds like a IntelliJ setting option.  What settings have you tried to change?

Comment: Please *always* include your OS. Solutions very often depend on the Operating System being used. Are you using Windows, Linux, Unix, OSX, BSD? Which version?

Comment: Added my OS, Looked through Intellij settings cant find the appropriate one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can disable it in the settings, un-tick the "Closures" box under ***Editor → Code Folding***:

[image: idea folding closures]